# Multiple independent Laravel Nova Dashboards in different routes?

Tags: laravel-nova

I am interested if there is a way to generate multiple independent Laravel Nova dashboards within the same multi-auth application?

Eg. 
Administrator Dashboard - {admin.example.com/nova/users}
Member Dashboard = {example.com/nova/home}

Answer (score 0):

You can find all info about creating additional dashboard in Laravel Nova 4 documentation

> [By this link](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/customization/dashboards.html)

For creating new dashboard use command

```
php artisan nova:dashboard MemberDashboard
```

Then in `app/Nova/Dashboards` you find `MemberDashboard.php` file

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova\Dashboards;

use Laravel\Nova\Dashboard;
use Laravel\Nova\Cards\Help;

class MemberDashboard extends Dashboard
{
    /**
     * Get the cards for the dashboard.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function cards()
    {
        return [
            Help,
        ];
    }
}
```

For changing default url you can add to `MemberDashboard` method

```
/**
 * Get the URI key of the dashboard.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function uriKey()
{
    return 'dashboard-for-member';
}
```

After that you must register this dashboard in `App/Providers/NovaServiceProvider`

```
use App\Nova\Dashboards\Main;
use App\Nova\Dashboards\MemberDashboard;

/**
 * Get the dashboards that should be listed in the Nova sidebar.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function dashboards()
{
    return [
        Main::make(),
        MemberDashboard::make()->canSee(function ($request) {
           return $request->user()->isMember();
        }),
    ];
}
```

For checking a role of the user you need add method `isMember()`
to User model that will return the bool value

Similarly you can create AdministratorDashboard and define different cards in it.